# Maui Android can't fetch API Data

Tags: android, blazor, maui-blazor

I made an API application and then I made an application that contains Blazor App, Maui App and Razor Class Library. Then I made a share for the component, services and libraries for both the Blazor application and Maui. When run the application in Blazor, it fetches data, and the web application  works Well. in Maui Desktop application fetches data and works well, but when you run the Maui Android application, a problem occurs in fetching data. Why?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services?view=net-maui-8.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/rest?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: Can you provide some codes and more information? This is difficult to solve the issue only by reading the words.